# error in asynctask : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
06-18 16:50:24.733: W/dalvikvm(1086): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:629)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:257)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1102)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:4641)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:3116)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.mythrii.tripview.BusFrom$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(BusFrom.java:274)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.mythrii.tripview.BusFrom$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(BusFrom.java:1)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-18 16:50:24.815: E/AndroidRuntime(1086):     ... 4 more
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086): Activity com.mythrii.tripview.BusFrom has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4062bcc0 that was originally added here
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mythrii.tripview.BusFrom has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4062bcc0 that was originally added here
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:85)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at com.mythrii.tripview.BusFrom.onCreate(BusFrom.java:109)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-18 16:50:30.571: E/WindowManager(1086):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you using some thing like 
`Toast.makeText(this, "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
or using Views inside the `doInBackground()` method.

If you want to use those use it in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Cool..No problems.. I am glad that you resolved your problem.. If my answer helps you please mark it as answer...thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views**

You cannot change the UI from a background thread.

The UI is run on the main thread, your ASyncTask is run on it's own thread.

If you want to notify the UI of a change from another Thread you will have to use handlers.

Take a look at :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5185155/413127

or the [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying your `Views` from the method `doInBackground` which runs on another thread. In android this is forbidden, instead you should modify the views from the `onPostExecute` method only.

Comment: thanks for ur reply how to handle exception in doInBackgroound method i already placed try catch block but it terminating the app

Comment: @raju Nobody can help you if you don't post some code. The basic ideea is that you can't modify the Views from `doInBackground`(like textView.setText). After you complete the task and the doInBackground method returns the method `onPostExecute` will be executed and there you should modify the views with the new data.

Comment: thank u alot i got solution from your reply its working for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the portion of the background task that updates the ui onto the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

This line make error

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1086): Caused by:Only the original thread that created 
a view hierarchy can touch its views".
```

May be you should try and show `Asyntack doInBackGround()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to the portion to the UI thread or you can use runOnUIThread method which is available from context

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this: instead of using asynktask use a thread.
Here it goes:

```
thread = new Thread() 
{
  @Override
  public void run() 
  {
    try
    {
      synchronized(this) 
      {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
  { 
           @Override
           public void run() 
           {                        
            your code goes here
           }
       });                  
     }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }         
 };
};
thread.start();
```