# Please can anyone explan this exception in LogCat

Tags: android, android-logcat

```
06-28 12:07:10.881: E/(930): {total=21 secs, date2=28-06-2012, time2=9:43:09 AM, time1=9:42:48 AM, date1=28-06-2012}
06-28 12:07:11.131: E/testing(930): exception:android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-28 12:07:11.160: E/(930): {total=24 secs, date2=28-06-2012, time2=10:45:02 AM, time1=10:44:38 AM, date1=28-06-2012}
06-28 12:07:11.601: E/testing(930): exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The observer is null.
```

Comment: you are trying to update the UI element from non UI thread...

Comment: make sure you are not calling it from a new Thread or AsyncTask.. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185015/updating-android-ui-using-threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- .ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread
  that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

looks you are trying to update the UI element from non UI thread.

should use `Handler` or `runOuUIThread` function of activities or `Asynctask` as per your need

Comment: sure http://www.aviyehuda.com/2010/12/android-multithreading-in-a-ui-environment/

Answer (score 1):

Look at code that is written in a seprate thread and is trying to update your application UI.

You need to put that code in run method of `runOnUiThread`.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
           // COde to update UI.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to modify UI components on a thread that is not the UI thread. Take a look at [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for updating UI components from non-UI threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads but all the views, and all the views related APIs, must be invoked from the **main thread** (also called **UI thread**.) To do this from a background thread, you need to use a **Handler**. A **Handler** is an object that will post messages back to the UI thread for you.