# Call MainActivity function outside the class

Tags: java, android, call

I try to show the ad outside the MainActivity. If I call showAd in this class it works good and show my ad, but when I call this function in my game class via implemented interface I have an error:
"Requires the main thread"

```
MMRequest request = new MMRequest(); ;  
    MMInterstitial interstitial;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        MMSDK.initialize(this);  
        interstitial = new MMInterstitial(this);               
        interstitial.setMMRequest(request);
        interstitial.setApid("xxxxxx");  

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();    

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        View gameView = initializeForView(new JumpJackieJump(new RequestHandler(), this), cfg);
        layout.addView(gameView);           

        setContentView(layout);  }

@Override
public void showAd() 
{   
    interstitial.fetch();
    interstitial.setListener(new RequestListenerImpl() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void requestCompleted(MMAd mmAd) 
        {
            interstitial.display();             
        }           
});
```

Comment: Please post more complete code. It's not clear from the snippet above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the main thread *is* the UI thread. (Keep in mind this is only for android - For more reference see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10190987/2864464)).

As per the Android documentation, you should [avoid updating the UI outside the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

`Additionally, the Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread.`

This being said, you may be able to do what you're looking for with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16483544/2864464).