# How to solve NullPointerException and ThreadException Error in android

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, thread-exceptions

I am getting a NullPointerException error in my code, I have narrowed it down to be this piece of code that is causing the exception. Can anyone help?

```
url = new URL(Http.toString());
```

---

```
  Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator<E> should be parameterized    User_menu.java  /RSBUYclient/src/com/example/rsbuyclient    line 141    Java Problem
04-24 11:34:29.756: W/System.err(32259): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And I have second problem is: When I click in this button I get the following exception: "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
How can I solve? thanks .

```
        private OnClickListener btsearchitemListener = new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

            final  Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
            //User_menu.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //User_menu.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                          
                    editText1.setHint("");

                    //URL url ;
                    //String Http_keyWord = "http://tw.search.bid.yahoo.com/search/auction/product?p=%s", Http, Keyword;
                    //String Http_keyWord = "https://tw.search.yahoo.com/search?p=u+zj6&fr=yfp&ei=utf-8&v=0", Http, Keyword;    

                    AllDatainfos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

                    Keyword = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
                    tvspottempp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp);
                    tvspottempp.setText("Keyword:"+Keyword);                                                

                    Http = String.format(Http_keyWord, UTF8EnCode(Keyword));
                    tvspottempp1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp1);
                    tvspottempp1.setText("Http:"+Http);
                 }  
              });   

            User_menu.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        try {                                           
                                url = new URL(Http.toString());
                                tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                                tvspottempp2.setText("url:"+url);

                                Document doc;                   
                                doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
                                tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp3);
                                tvspottempp2.setText("doc:"+doc);

                                Elements paramDocuments = doc.select("#srp_result_list, #srp_gaze_list").select(".grid-type.yui3-g > *");

                                Iterator localIterator = paramDocuments.select("#srp_result_list, #srp_gaze_list").select(".grid-type.yui3-g > *").iterator();

                              while (true)
                              {
                                if (!localIterator.hasNext())
                                  return;
                                Element localElement1 = (Element)localIterator.next();
                                try
                                {
                                  SearchResultItem localSearchResultItem = new SearchResultItem();
                                  Element localElement2 = localElement1.select(".wrap").first();
                                  parsePhoto(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);
                                  parsePrice(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);
                                  parseTitle(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);                    
                                }
                                catch (Exception localException2)
                                {
                                  localException2.printStackTrace();
                                }
                              }

                        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch (Exception localException1)
                            {
                              localException1.printStackTrace();
                            }   try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000) ;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
                    }
                });


                 }  
              };
```

---

```
    04-24 12:25:31.231: W/System.err(9995): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at com.example.rsbuyclient.User_menu$1$2.run(User_menu.java:138)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4893)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at com.example.rsbuyclient.User_menu$1.onClick(User_menu.java:135)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 12:25:36.256: W/Choreographer(9995): Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
```

Comment: the second problem is because you are updating ui from a thread

Comment: Can used "runOnUiThread" ?

Comment: yes but better use asynctask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating UI (TextView settext) on thread thats why your getting error.

```
                      // ui stuff updating that's why showing error
                      tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                      tvspottempp2.setText("url:"+url);
```

[Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Comment: 04-24 12:25:31.231: W/System.err(9995): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):  at com.example.rsbuyclient.User_menu$1$2.run(User_menu.java:138)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):  at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4893)

Comment: 04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-24 12:25:31.236: W/System.err(9995):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the UI from threads. So the error occur. If you want to update ui from thread then use handlers. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5185155/1265724) SO Thread for more info

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        url = new URL(Http.toString());
                        tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                        tvspottempp2.setText("url:"+url);

                        Document doc;                   
                        doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
                        tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp3);
                        tvspottempp2.setText("doc:"+doc);
                    }
                });
```

For more information for using ui thread you can take reference of [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread).