# Activity crash when I reload it

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to do an activity that saves with sharedpreferences a int that you choose in a spinner and I'm trying to make that when the user click in a menu the activity reload with the different value of the sharedpreferences int (previously chosed in the spinner), but when the user reload the app it crashes with this message:

```
08-19 19:02:56.145: D/AndroidRuntime(23142): Shutting down VM
08-19 19:02:56.145: W/dalvikvm(23142): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4164bd40)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142): Process: com.example.fluviales, PID: 23142
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at com.example.fluviales.Home_fragment$1$1.run(Home_fragment.java:49)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-19 19:02:56.146: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The weird thing to me is that if I reload the activity using

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

the activity crash, but if I close the app in the multitask and the re-open it the code works!

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnPageChangeListener{

private static final String PREFS_NAME = "ciudad";
private static final String DATA_TAG = "ciudad";
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;

public ViewPager mPager;
public PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
String[] ciudades = { "Desde Paraná", "Desde Santa Fe", "Desde el pozo", "Desde abogacia"};
public int ciudad;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = MainActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int ciudad_sp = sharedPref.getInt("ciudad", 0);

    final TextView tvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.debug);
    tvv.setText(String.valueOf(ciudad_sp));


    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.opciones, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    sp.setSelection(ciudad_sp);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                ciudad = position;
                Toast.makeText(parentView.getContext(), ciudades[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                 


                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("ciudad", position);
                editor.commit();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            mPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    });

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    createMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

private void createMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Reload");
    {
        mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('a');
        mnu1.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}



/**
 * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
 * sequence.
 */
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = MainActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int ciudad_sp = sharedPref.getInt("ciudad", 0);


        if(ciudad_sp == 0){
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    return new Home_fragment();
                case 1:
                    return new Next_fragment();                 
            }
        }else if(ciudad_sp == 1){
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    return new Home_fragment_staFe();
                case 1:
                    return new Next_fragment_staFe();                   
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

}


@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    String [] hola = {"Siguiente cole", "Siguiente siguiente cole" };
    setTitle(hola[position]);
}


}
```

And this is my Home_fragment fragment

```
public class Home_fragment extends Fragment{

public int numeroDelArray, cuantosQuedan, HoraActual_en_minutos;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.inicio, container, false);


    final int[] horas = { 1,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,11,11,12,13,13,14,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20,21,21,22,23 };
    final int[] minutos = { 0,0,0,10,10,20,0,10,30,20,40,20,30,50,40,0,40,50,10,10,20,0,10,30,20,40,30,50,0,40,0,50,10,20,0,20,10,30,40,50 };

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Write your code here to update the UI.
                        numeroDelArray = checkHour();
                        // Down here is the error that the logcat shows
                        TextView tv_minutos = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.minutos);
                        TextView tv_horaDelQueSale = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textoQueQueda);
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                        HoraActual_en_minutos = (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 ) + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                        cuantosQuedan = horas[numeroDelArray]*60 + minutos[numeroDelArray] - HoraActual_en_minutos;

                        if(cuantosQuedan > 60){
                            tv_minutos.setText("+60");
                        }else{
                            tv_minutos.setText(String.valueOf(cuantosQuedan));
                        }
                        tv_horaDelQueSale.setText("QUE SALE A LAS " + String.valueOf(String.format("%02d", horas[numeroDelArray])) + ":" + String.valueOf(String.format("%02d", minutos[numeroDelArray])));

                        }


                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();


    return rootView;
}

private int checkHour() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] horas = { 1,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,11,11,12,13,13,14,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20,21,21,22,23 };
    int[] minutos = { 0,0,0,10,10,20,0,10,30,20,40,20,30,50,40,0,40,50,10,10,20,0,10,30,20,40,30,50,0,40,0,50,10,20,0,20,10,30,40,50 };


    int minutosQueUso = 9999, lugarQueQueda = 0;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int HoraActualenminutos = (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 ) + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if (horas.length != minutos.length){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No acomodaste bien la hora de los minutos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        for(int lugar = 0; lugar < minutos.length; lugar++){
            if((horas[lugar]*60 + minutos[lugar] - HoraActualenminutos) > 0 && (horas[lugar]*60 + minutos[lugar] - HoraActualenminutos) < minutosQueUso ){

                minutosQueUso = horas[lugar]*60 + minutos[lugar] - HoraActualenminutos;
                lugarQueQueda = lugar;
            }
        }
    }

    return lugarQueQueda;



}}
```

And other question I have is that if someone know a method to reload the activity when the user change the spinner value, I tried to reload the activity in my `setOnItemSelected` but it generates a infinite loop, thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying UI from a non-UI thread. You shouldn't do this.

For more info, have a look at the following question and answer:

[Updating Android UI using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185015/updating-android-ui-using-threads)