# How to change android notifications color and fontsize?

Tags: android, push-notification

Been browsing through android developers guide but couldnt seem to find any that will allow me to change background colors, text colors and fontsizes.

Any help towards the right resource will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the ui-elemnts of your application, then you can customize the main.xml

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_view2"
  android:text="Font size 25dp or dip (Density-independent-Pixels)"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="#FF0000"
  android:textSize="25dp"
  />
```

Code is taken from this link https://android--examples.blogspot.se/2015/01/textview-font-size-in-android.html

Howevver, If you want to update the ui at runtime, then you most send a request to the ui.
Check this thread [Updating Android UI using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185015/updating-android-ui-using-threads)
Both Franco and user634618 have pretty good answers regarding this.