# App crashes with thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm very new to Java programming and I'm having troubles with while loops in Threads. I post here an example where I use the while loop.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean running = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {

                try{Thread.sleep(1000);} 
                catch(InterruptedException e){}

                running = false;
                text.setText("false!");

                running = true;

                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
                catch(InterruptedException e){}

                text.setText("True!");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

When running is set to false, the Thread doesn't run and the app does not show anything. When running is set to true, the app crashes after
      text.setText("false!");

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Read the exception message ( and post it in your question too). It should tell you, you can't update UI outside of the UI thread

Comment: Look into the logcat and post the stacktrace

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5185140/4391450)  is the simplest to use

Comment: Android is the wrong platform to learn Java threads, IMO. Try a desktop app

Comment: thread sleeps your UI, meaning you cannot update UI during that time. either use Handler or Looper or an AsyncTask to update UI after your background action @Jens

Comment: you can't update UI in background Thread. You need to update UI in Main thread. For this you can use:

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your code goes here
        }
    });

Comment: Thank you all very much! I just didn't know this thing! sorry, i'm just a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access textView from thread, you can only change view objects from main thread

Comment: The object is final. It can be accessed

Comment: it does not matter, you cannot change gui objects from threads rather than main thread.

Comment: @cricket_007 Even if TextView is final, we can not access it on background or other thread. UI must be updated on mainThread. Here we can use Activity.runOnUIThread instead. or an Handler

Comment: I understand that. Maybe you can re-write the answer instead of saying "access" to "update"

Comment: plz read this post, it completely answered to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185015/updating-android-ui-using-threads