# Android TextView issue in run()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, textview

```
class BTCSync extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            while(!BTC && MainPage.BTC){
                TextView BTCPer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblBTCPer);
                BTCPer.setText(BTCProgress+"%");
                if(BTCProgress == 100) {
                    BTCPer.setText("100%");
                    BTC = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is where `findViewById` my label is lblBTCPer.

The reason I have it in `run()` is that this block needs to run until the value hits 100.

I know that usually, you would have to throw in the View v but then it would negate the void run().

I looked for a few solutions but I haven't found a working example.

I also believe I posted this already just yesterday but I can't seem to find it anywhere. It's not under my account and I distinctly remember posting it and waiting for responses.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById()` is a function of either *Android* [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int)) or [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)). Your `BTCSync` class does not extend neither of those.

Most likely [Timertask or Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20330355/3290339) would be a better fit for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the findViewById problem, you're trying to do UI work on a non-UI thread. You'll need to use runOnUiThread() or you're going to get a crash:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            BTCPer.setText(BTCProgress+"%");
            if(BTCProgress == 100) {
                BTCPer.setText("100%");
                BTC = true;
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Android app have **only one UI thread**, and the Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe and must always be manipulated on the UI thread.

In order to update ui in other thread, you could use `handler`, here is [ref](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#top_of_page)

and here is a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185015/updating-android-ui-using-threads)

Answer (score 1):

Android forbids **altering the UI** (for example setting a text of a textview) **outside of the UI thread**.

If you are able to call this line

```
TextView BTCPer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblBTCPer);
```

then that means that your thread is defined inside your activity, because `findViewById()` is not a `Thread`'s function. In this case:

```
class BTCSync extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            while(!BTC && MainPage.BTC){
                TextView BTCPer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblBTCPer);
                // make sure you enable lambdas
                runOnUiThread(() -> BTCPer.setText(BTCProgress+"%"));
                if(BTCProgress == 100) {
                    BTCPer.setText("100%");
                    BTC = true;
                }
            }
        }
```